# How would I implement formula into this function?

Tags: python, function

I have worked out that in order to find the amount of plastic required, I need to calculate the volume of the brick:

Height x Length x Width

After the calculation, I need to times this volume by the weight per brick, in this case, 7, to get the amount of plastic required:

Volume x Weight Per Cubic CM.

I know what I need to do, I just don't know how to implement it.

```
def amount_of_plastic(width_brick, height_brick, length_brick, number_of_bricks):
    """Given the dimensions of a brick (width, height, length in cm) and the number of bricks ordered, calculate how much plastic, in grams, is required (if a cubic centimetre weighs 7 grams)."""

    # INSERT YOUR CODE BELOW THIS LINE FOR CALCULATING THE 
    # AMOUNT OF PLASTIC AND RETURNING THE RESULT (DO NOT CHANGE
    # THE HEADER OF THE FUNCTION WHICH HAS BEEN PROVIDED FOR YOU
    # ABOVE)


# DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE
# The code below automatically tests your function
# following the approach described in 
# Block 2 Part 4 (Page 207 and further).
# Before making any changes to this file, 
# when you run it, you will get an AssertionError. 
# Once you have completed the file with correct
# code, the AssertionError should no longer appear and
# "tests passed" will appear in the shell.


def test_amount_of_plastic():
    """Test the amount_of_plastic() function."""
    # Test for brick with dimensions 0, 0, 0 and 
    # order of 20 bricks
    assert amount_of_plastic(0, 0, 0, 20) == 0

    # Test for brick with dimensions 1, 1, 1 and 
    # order of 0 bricks
    assert amount_of_plastic(1, 1, 1, 0) == 0

    # Test for brick with dimensions 1, 1, 1 and 
    # order of 20 bricks
    assert amount_of_plastic(1, 1, 1, 20) == 140

    # Test for brick with dimensions 1, 2, 3 and 
    # order of 100 bricks
    assert amount_of_plastic(1, 2, 3, 100) == 4200

    print ("tests passed") 


test_amount_of_plastic()
```

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have explained above exactly what my issue is so I don't really understand the comment, however, I will repeat again. 
I have a function, I have the formula, I need to enter the formula into the function so the function works.

Comment: You seem to want someone to do your homework for you. What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've done the working out, I have found how I would get the result. I just can't seem to figure out how to correctly insert my solution into the code. 
I don't understand how to insert my formula so that when "assert amount_of_plastic(1, 1, 1, 20)" for instance is called, it will find the volume by multiplying the height, width and length together. Multiplying that volume by 7 and returning that number by 20 in this case which is the amount of bricks. @JohnColeman

Comment: The problem is that you show absolutely no code of your own. You show code that obviously comes from the problem statement but you do not even try anything of your own. You also do not try to use the parameter `number_of_bricks` so answering your question would not suffice to solve the problem. Try some code of your own and show it to us, then we can help you further.

Comment: `volume = width_brick*height_brick*length_brick
required = volume*7
amount_of_plastic = required*number_of_bricks`

This is the code I tried to implement, I still get an assertion error.

Comment: @TylerOsborne take that code you wrote in the comment above, change the `volume = ` with `return` and simply paste it under the big comment in the top of the file (as attached here). Make sure it is indented as the comment

Comment: Are you familiar with `return`? Calculating the amount and then doing nothing with that calculated amount isn't going to help. By the way, if you had shown your efforts in the question itself (and not later on in the comments) you would probably have gotten a much more positive response.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot figure out for the life of me how I am supposed to syntax it. I have tried the above and I am drawing a blank. I've been in my python shell for the past hour trying to figure out how I can calculate them, even with a single line but nothing works.

Comment: Please edit your best attempt into the question itself. Make sure that the code that you add reflects the indentation that you are using.

Comment: `return width_brick*height_brick*length_brick*7*number_of_bricks` I think that sorted it. Thanks for the help. Sorry it was annoying.

Comment: @TylerOsborne Glad you discovered the solution. Python is a fun language once you get the hang of it. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

`return width_brick*height_brick*length_brick*7*number_of_bricks`

Answer (score 0):

```
def amount_of_plastic(width_brick, height_brick, length_brick, number_of_bricks):
```

using the input you got for width, height, length, number of bricks, and 7 gr needed per 1 cm3, you can calculate the total grams needed:

```
plasticNeeded = width_brick * height_brick * length_brick * number_of_bricks * 7
```

then output the result

```
return plasticNeeded
```